# How to display decoded html text with jQuery with data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JSON text that has a body tag with text like:

```
[
    {
      "body":&lt;ul&gt;\n&lt;li&gt;Place item in the&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;box.&lt;\/strong,
      "category":"A",
      "title":"A box",
      "keywords":"bread bag tag, milk bag tag, elastic band, rubber band, twist tie, rope, twine, string, hemp, ribbon, bow, burlap, staple";
   }
]
```

(The original JSON file is in correct syntax)
The JSON file has many tags like that with title, body, and keywords. I am supposed to search with keywords (from input box in html), match and then display title and body. I can display the title with no problem. I can display body like:

```
<ul><li>Place item in the <strong>box</strong></li>
```

I have tried using .html(), .text(), $.parseHTML in all combinations.
Here's the code snippet:

```
    $.getJSON(url, function(response)
    {
        if(response.length)
        {
            $('#table_item').empty();
            var content = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
            {
            if((response[i].keywords).indexOf(key) != -1)
            {
                content += '<div class="row"><div class="column"><div>';
                content += response[i].title;
                content += '</div></div><div class="column"><div id="bbody"><p>';
                var bodyJson = response[i].body;
                $("#bbody").html(bodyJson).text();
                $("#bbody").html($("#abody").html(bodyJson)); //THIS LINE
                content += '</p></div></div></div>';
                }
            }
            $('#table_item').append(content);
        }
    });
```

What I can't do is write the way it's supposed to be, that is bullets and bold:

Place item in the box

Let me know if you need more info, or if I'm asking the question in a wrong way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm going to assume the JSON you receive from the server is valid JSON? Because that snippet isn't. Just to exclude that as the cause of the issue.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes it is, sorry I'll let make that clear in the question

Comment: I took a quick look and noticed that you're creating HTML with `id="bbody"` in a loop, but an `id` is supposed to be unique. Plus, you cannot call `$("#bbody")` on an element that doesn't exist yet; you have a HTML string but it's not part of the dom yet. Why not just insert it, like the other parts? Edit: fixed JSON, here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/y9tw2qkj/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: @ChrisG this works perfectly. Thank you so much! I'm wondering about the thing you said that the element doesn't exist yet, does it not exist until I do the .append() ?

Comment: Until you do append, all you have is a string. The browser has no idea that the string contains HTML, much less that it contains an element with a certain `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XoxNqN) for you to check out. I used `$.parseHTML` to take the escaped html into a node object, then from there I appended it by using the nodeValue property.

When you are receiving JSON from a server, be sure to use JSON.parse to transform it into JS object instead of a JSON object.

Check out [$.parseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)for more information.

Hope this helps you out. Message me if you need more help. :D cheers!

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON object. And `$.getJSON` parses the JSON into an object before passing it to the callback.

Comment: The payload/response is still a string. So it's needs to be workable, i.e. made into an object that can be manipulated. That's all I meant. My bad long day.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a tool to do the decoding

```
<script src="https://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js"></script>
```

Then change your code to this:

```
content += Encoder.htmlDecode(unescape(bodyJson));
```

Then you don't have to use jQuery to .html()

Comment: This works like a charm. Is there no way where I can still get the result without using a third party script?

Comment: No. You can only decode one entity at a time. Read the javascript for the htmlDecode function in encoder.js  For example, to convert &copy; you first have to provide the matching char code which is 169. So then you can do String.fromCharCode(169), but you can't do that to a whole line of HTML.